# AWS::Serverless::Function CodeUri ignored by 'sam build' (whole project folder copied)?

Tags: aws-sam

`sam build` copies whole project folder instead of lambda function folder(s).

I have this project structure:

```
.
├── aws.yaml
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── src
    ├── postAuthentication
    │   └── main.js
    └── postConfirmation
        └── main.js
```

My sam (cloudformation) template looks like this (abbreviated):

```
LambdaPostAuthentication:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Runtime: nodejs12.x
    CodeUri: ./src/postAuthentication
    Handler: ./src/postAuthentication/main.handler

LambdaPostConfirmation:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Runtime: nodejs12.x
    CodeUri: ./src/postConfirmation
    Handler: ./src/postConfirmation/main.handler
```

`sam build` gives me:

```
.
└── build
    ├── LambdaPostAuthentication
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   └── src
    │       ├── postAuthentication
    │       │   └── main.js
    │       └── postConfirmation
    │           └── main.js
    ├── LambdaPostConfirmation
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   └── src
    │       ├── postAuthentication
    │       │   └── main.js
    │       └── postConfirmation
    │           └── main.js
    └── template.yaml
```

What I expect to get is the following:

```
.
└── build
    ├── LambdaPostAuthentication
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   └── src
    │       └── postAuthentication
    │           └── main.js

    ├── LambdaPostConfirmation
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   └── src
    │       └── postConfirmation
    │           └── main.js
    └── template.yaml
```

I also tried absolute paths for `CodeUri` and `Handler` but to no avail.

Comment: Same problem, no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both `./src/postAuthentication` and `./src/postConfirmation` have a package.json file in them.